# gstreamer using tee and queue not working on mac osx

Tags: gstreamer

test both  OSX 14.2.1 Sonoma and OSX 11.7.10 Big Sur.

gstreamer version: 1.24.1

gstreamer is installed with official pkg.

the following doesn't work anymore.

```bash
gst-launch-1.0 audiotestsrc name=audio_source freq=215.0 ! tee name=t ! queue ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! autoaudiosink t. ! queue ! wavescope ! videoconvert ! autovideosink
```

got error

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
Got context from element 'autovideosink0': gst.gl.GLDisplay=context, gst.gl.GLDisplay=(GstGLDisplay)"\(GstGLDisplayCocoa\)\ gldisplaycocoa0";
Redistribute latency...
Redistribute latency...
Pipeline is PREROLLED ...
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
Redistribute latency...
New clock: GstAudioSinkClock
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstAudioTestSrc:audio_source: Internal data stream error.
Additional debug info:
../libs/gst/base/gstbasesrc.c(3175): gst_base_src_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstAudioTestSrc:audio_source:
streaming stopped, reason not-negotiated (-4)
Execution ended after 0:00:00.139762836
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstQueue:queue1: Internal data stream error.
Additional debug info:
../plugins/elements/gstqueue.c(1035): gst_queue_handle_sink_event (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstQueue:queue1:
streaming stopped, reason not-negotiated (-4)
Freeing pipeline ...
```